# .NET Framework 4.7.2 Startup Authentication Logic

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How can this .NET Core 3.1 authentication code be written in .NET Framework 4.7.2 in the startup file?

services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options))
    .AddCookie();
```

There is an [GitHub sample](https://github.com/JimXu199545/NetCoreWeb/tree/master/NetCoreB2C) which can help you in Azure AD B2C OpenIDConnent Authentication using .Net Core 3.1

Comment: In framework Framework 4.7.2,,OpenIdConnectDefaults isn't recognized. This is because the reference using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect isn't recognized. I need this because my existing system in use targets this framework and would like to take advantage of Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Can you please share the current code and the error details when you are trying to make the changes. And what do you mean by taking advantage of Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to migrate my project from framework to .net core 3.1